# Return the most occurring value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently trying to select the most common value my table look like this

```
SALES:
-----------------------------------
NAME    | QUANTITY  
banana     8
pizza      1
banana     2
pizza      5
milk       2
banana     1
burger     4
---------------------------------
```

I tried this query

```
SELECT `name`, COUNT(`name`) AS `value_occur` 
FROM `SALES`
GROUP BY `name`
ORDER BY `value_occur` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

resulting in:

```
banana   3
```

but, what I want is a way to multiply it with the quantity.

Comment: Which product? [Edit] your question to include the tag for Microsoft SQL Server [tag:sql-server], [tag:mysql] or [tag:oracle].

Comment: As C-Pound Guru said, You should always specify what server you are using. Is this `PostgreSQL` or `MySQL`?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a query like this:

```
SELECT name, (count(name)*sum(quantity)) AS TOTAL_QUANTITY
FROM SALES
ORDER BY TOTAL_QUANTITY DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I assume that you want the total quantity of each product and you want to select the most recurrent product.

(Try this in w3c editor And Will work, there seems to be some sort of issue with sql server that I Will investigate asap)

Comment: This query won't work, it will give you an error like
'Column 'SALES.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
'

Comment: can you please run the same query and check again?
if it won't give you an error then i'll remove it my friend..

Comment: try this: SELECT customerName, (count(customerName)*sum(customerId)) AS TOTAL_QUANTITY
FROM customers
ORDER BY TOTAL_QUANTITY DESC
LIMIT 1 here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

I will be happy though to understand why you think this should fail, there is a big possibility that I am missing something in my knowledge and I want to learn something ;)

Comment: I tried, it works in W3schools editor where doesn't work in SQLserver.
Can you please edit your Answer so i can remove Downvote.

Comment: Thanks,  any idea of tue reason?

Answer (score 1):

Just take the sum of the quantity.  That appears to be what you want:

```
SELECT name, SUM(quantity) AS sumq
FROM SALES
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY sumq DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want answer like `banana 33` then go for below query

```
SELECT name, (COUNT(name)*SUM(Quantity)) AS value_occur 
FROM SALES
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY value_occur DESC
LIMIT 1;
```